Measure theory for non-Hausdorff topological spaces
I m interested in measures on non-Hausdorff spaces but have not been able to find anything specific beyond the general standard measure theory.
Can anyone please point me to references that focus on non-Hausdorff topological spaces.

I think your question is too broad. What exactly do you want to study when it comes to (Borel?) measures on not necessarily Hausdorff spaces?

Possibly of interest is the following, but I don't remember whether non-Hausdorff spaces are considered: Richard Curtis Willmott, Hausdorff Measures in Topological Spaces, Ph.D. Dissertation (under Maurice Sion), University of British Columbia, June 1965, vii + 119 pages. See also the end of my answer to the Mathematics Stack Exchange question Metric dimensions properties not in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

@DaveLRenfro Many thanks, I will look it up.

@Jakobian I am interested in integration theory and whether some sort of differential calculus is possible on a non-Hausdorff space.
